# Spring RestTemplate does not allow for persistent https connections

Tags: spring-mvc, ssl, https, resttemplate, keep-alive

I want to make use of persistent http connections using Spring RestTemplate when accessing a REST api over https. I cannot make it work; a new connection is created for each request and SSL handshake takes place each time.
Is it possible to have reusable connections over https with RestTemplate and if so, how to configure it?

I set up a RestTemplate to make requests over https. That works correctly.
However I notice in the logs that a new SSL handshake takes place with every request.

I set up a RestTemplate in a test as follows:

```java
@Before
public void setupPersistentHttpConnectionBackedRestTemplate() {
    final SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
        sslContext,
        new String[] { "TLSv1.2" },
        null,
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    final Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
        .register("https", sslSocketFactory)
        .build();
    final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
    final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .build();
    final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    restTemplate.getRestTemplate().setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
}
```

Then I make several calls using this RestTemplate like this:

```java
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("/tomcat/sleep?millis={millis}", HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, String.class, SLEEP_DURATION);
```

I investigated the code of spring-mvc and apache and notice the following.
In Spring RestTemplate execute method, a new request is created and then the request gets executed and the result returned.

```java
            ClientHttpRequest request = createRequest(url, method);
            if (requestCallback != null) {
                requestCallback.doWithRequest(request);
            }
            response = request.execute();
            handleResponse(url, method, response);
            return (responseExtractor != null ? responseExtractor.extractData(response) : null);
```

That in turn ends in calling HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory where a new http context is created every time:

```java
    @Override
    public ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod) throws IOException {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

        HttpUriRequest httpRequest = createHttpUriRequest(httpMethod, uri);
        postProcessHttpRequest(httpRequest);
        HttpContext context = createHttpContext(httpMethod, uri);
        if (context == null) {
            context = HttpClientContext.create();
        }
...
```

When following the chain of calls during the request execute call, I end up in apache MainClientExec. There it tries to reuse a connection based on the route and the context user token. After the request is executed, the user token is retrieved from the context and stored for further lookup.

```java
    @Override
    public CloseableHttpResponse execute(
            final HttpRoute route,
            final HttpRequestWrapper request,
            final HttpClientContext context,
            final HttpExecutionAware execAware) throws IOException, HttpException {
...
        Object userToken = context.getUserToken();

        final ConnectionRequest connRequest = connManager.requestConnection(route, userToken);
...
            if (userToken == null) {
                userToken = userTokenHandler.getUserToken(context);
                context.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.USER_TOKEN, userToken);
            }
            if (userToken != null) {
                connHolder.setState(userToken);
            }
...
```

In the case of a https connection, the user token gets retrieved from the SSL principal, that in turn gets it from the SSL certificate:

```java
    @Override
    public Object getUserToken(final HttpContext context) {
...
        if (userPrincipal == null) {
            final HttpConnection conn = clientContext.getConnection();
            if (conn.isOpen() && conn instanceof ManagedHttpClientConnection) {
                final SSLSession sslsession = ((ManagedHttpClientConnection) conn).getSSLSession();
                if (sslsession != null) {
                    userPrincipal = sslsession.getLocalPrincipal();
                }
            }
        }
```

```java
    public Principal getLocalPrincipal() {
        if (this.cipherSuite.keyExchange != KeyExchange.K_KRB5 && this.cipherSuite.keyExchange != KeyExchange.K_KRB5_EXPORT) {
            return this.localCerts == null ? null : this.localCerts[0].getSubjectX500Principal();
        } else {
            return this.localPrincipal == null ? null : this.localPrincipal;
        }
    }
```

The PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager tries to return reusable connections based on the route and the state (in which the user token has been stored).

But since the RestTemplate starts with a new request with a new context each time, the uset token is lost and the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager can not find a reusable connection and thus creates a new one every time.

I would expect that the RestRemplate could create a request that re-uses that connection instead of creating a new one every time.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve the same and the only way I see to do this is by extending HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory to set a UserToken, in this case a Principal cert.getSubjectDN() then override createHttpContext(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri)

```
@Override
protected HttpContext createHttpContext(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setUserToken(userToken);
    return context;
}
```

Comment: Tried doing this, but it didn't change anything. SSL handshakes are still occurring with each and every transaction.